# Trigonometry distance finding

Tags: java, trigonometry

I am trying to find the extra distance of a golf shot that occurs because the people hitting are hitting off a higher ground than ground level. I have the equation; however, after entering in the distance hit and the angle of the shot, all that I am given is tangent=0. Is there something I am missing in order to have the extra distance shown after I run the program?

```
public class HittingBay {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double distanceX = 0;
        double radians = 0;
        double extraDistance = 0;
        double rads;
        double degs = 0;
        double tanA = 0;
        double angle = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter in distance hit");
        distanceX = scan.nextInt(); // distanceX means how far shot track man thought
        System.out.println("Enter in angle of shot");
        angle = scan.nextInt();

        // Calculate tangent
        tanA = Math.tan(degs);
        System.out.println("Tangent = " + tanA);

        extraDistance = distanceX * (tanA * angle);
        extraDistance = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("extra distance= " + extraDistance);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never assign a value to `degs`, so it's still `0` when you call `Math.tan(degs)`.  Perhaps you meant to do something with the angle the user input?

Comment: Also be sure to convert your angle from degrees to radians.  The trigonometric math methods only properly work in radians.

Comment: Why do you compute extraDistance, then ignore that value and overwrite it by accepting a new int from the user?

Answer (score 1):

`degs` is only being initialized to 0 and has not been changed. The tangent of 0 is 0. What you need to do is give `deg` a value. Perhaps, use user input. Then you would need to covert degrees into radians, as the trigonometric functions of Java take radians as parameters. Try the following:

```
double tanResult = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(degs));
```

Or in your case:

```
tanA = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(degs));
```

For scanning the degrees:

```
System.out.println("Enter Degrees: ");
degs = scan.nextDouble();
```

Also something to note: `extraDistance` is being computed but overwritten by the user input. Make sure to verify the use of `extraDistance`. You must also verify the logic and correctness of the formula you are using.

Comment: What do you suggest I use as my initialization value to degrees in order for it to be able to change depending on what the user inputs?

Comment: @TaylorColeman Initializing it as 0 is fine. After storing the input to degs it should work fine. Get the user input and set degs equal to that. Also, check the formula you're using for extraDistance

Answer (score 0):

tan(degs)? See the value of degs. It doesn't change from 0 in your program. Please change it by making degs=angles or degs=angle/pi.

Answer (score 0):

```
extraDistance = distanceX * (tanA * angle)
```

This equation is so not correct. Multiplying the angle by its tangent is meaningless. A naïve approach would be

```
extraDistance = distance * ( Math.sec(angle_in_radians) - 1 )
```

but the ball will be travelling in an arc, not a straight line, so even that formula understates the extra distance for anything but the shallowest angles.